# Linear Independence of abstract vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've seen this asked many times in problems and don't understand how to concretely prove it.

True or False? Explain the assertion or find a counterexample.
If $\{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$ is a linearly independent set in some vector space $V$, then
also the set $\{u_1, u_1 + u_2, u_1 + u_2 + u_3\}$ is linearly independent.

Does anybody know the proper way to prove this?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Asking "does anybody know ..." isn't the best invitation for help. You're more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show what you tried and where you are stuck. You could begin by creating some numerical examples for yourself, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so you can see concretely what's going on and decide whether the assertion is true or false. Then tackle the abstract version.

Comment: Okay thank you Ethan, I'll work on my way of formulating the answer. I appreciate it and solved the question now with the hints provided below. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. You got lots of answers quickly this time. In the future it's really best to try before asking here. You learn more that way.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Do it indirectly. Assume $\{u_1,u_1+u_2,u_1+u_2+u_3\}$ is linearly dependent and conclude that $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: proceed according to the definition, and build a linear combination of the three vectors. Hence
$$
\alpha u_1 + \beta (u_1+u_2) + \gamma (u_1+u_2+u_3) =0.
$$
Then collect, and try to use the indipendence of $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove by definition looking for $a,b,c\neq 0$ such that

$$ax_1+b(x_1+x_2)+c(x_1+x_2+x_3)=0$$

$$\iff (a+b+c)x_1+(b+c)x_2+cx_3=0$$

and since $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are linearly independent finding

- $a+b+c=0$
- $b+c=0$
- $c=0$

which is true if and only if $a=b=c=0$ thus also the set $\{u_1, u_1 + u_2, u_1 + u_2 + u_3\}$ is linearly independent.

More directly we can easily see that we can't obtain $u_1 + u_2 + u_3$ from $u_1$ and $u_1 + u_2$ since they don't contain $u_3$ and also $u_1$ and $u_1 + u_2$ are clearly linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Take $a_1,a_2,a_3$ such that $a_1u_1+a_2(u_1+u_2)+a_3(u_1+u_2+u_3)=0$. This means that$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a_1+a_2+a_3=0\\a_2+a_3=0\\a_3=0.\end{array}\right.$$But the only solution of this system is $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$.